# How to set the max height for datagridview row while using autoresize?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to resize the row height of `DataGridView` based upon height of individual cells in a row.

For which I am using

```
dt_grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

but I also want to limit it to a maximum size beyond which it shouldn't increase the row height.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not supported by `DataGridView`. You can either set `AutoSizeRowsMode` as you did, or have the content in one line and truncatenated at the end of column(s) width.

However, there's a workaround you can use to achive a very similar effect you're asking for. Let's say you have a `Description` column, which causes you a trouble. Then, if you set the column to `AllCells`, you can truncatenate it in the source, i.e. in SQL this way:

```
SELECT ID, CASE 
               WHEN LEN(Description) > 150                          -- check length
                   THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Description,1,150),'...')  -- truncatenate, if needed
               ELSE Description                                     -- else keep it as is
           END 
FROM MyTable;
```

You won't get the long text precisely finishing to a pixel, but it will be totally fine and not intereferring with user experience.